# How to upgrade sed to 4.5 on Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, sed

I want to try the newest `sed` utility on Ubuntu Server 18.04. I've tried below command but still not able to upgrade it. How can I do that?

```
root@u1804:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease [64.4 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Fetched 311 kB in 7s (47.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
97 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@u1804:~# 
root@u1804:~# apt show sed
Package: sed
Version: 4.4-2
Priority: required
Essential: yes
Section: utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Clint Adams <clint@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 328 kB
Pre-Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
Homepage: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/
Task: minimal
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 182 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Description: GNU stream editor for filtering/transforming text
 sed reads the specified files or the standard input if no
 files are specified, makes editing changes according to a
 list of commands, and writes the results to the standard
 output.
root@u1804:~#
root@u1804:~# apt install --only-upgrade sed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sed is already the newest version (4.4-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
root@u1804:~#
```

Comment: You really should not be logged in as root. Really. And you should upgrade those 97 packages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll take it and upgrade the packages.

Comment: Why do you need an updated sed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: the latest version of GNU sed at the time of writing is 4.7, not 4.5.*

Here is an alternative option: compile directly from the source tarball, using two very useful features of GNU source packages.

- You can install your new version of `sed` under any other name you want, so that it will not interfere with your current `sed`; in this answer I will use `sed47`.
- The `make uninstall` command is supported, which allows you to cleanly uninstall it if you no longer need it.

First install all the build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep sed
```

Get the source and extract

```
cd
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/sed-4.7.tar.xz
tar xf sed-4.7.tar.xz
rm sed-4.7.tar.xz    # optional
cd sed-4.7
```

Configure, build and install. Note the `--program-suffix` parameter to `configure`, which tells the build system to append `47` to the name of all executables.

```
./configure --program-suffix=47
make
sudo make install
```

You can now use the new sed with the command `sed47`, consult its manual page with `man sed47`, etc. When/if you want to uninstall it, do

```
cd ~/sed-4.7
sudo make uninstall
```

If you have deleted the `sed-4.7` directory, you can recreate it by repeating the installation instructions above (at least up to `make`).

If you want to use it as your "main" version of sed, you can create an alias:

```
alias sed=sed47
```

In this case I recommend subscribing to the [info-gnu mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/info-gnu) to get announcements about new releases, which may contain important bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` application is not comprehensive, so you can
[get version 4.5 from Ubuntu 18.10 (*cosmic*)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/sed) repository.

Usually this method is not recommended, but you can proceed if you are sure (**you will not get security updates for this package installed this way**):

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sed/sed_4.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./sed_4.5-1_amd64.deb
```

As the result this packages will be listed as locally installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this replace the 4.4-2 version or install side by side? If it's side by side, which one it runs when I type `sed`?

Comment: BTW, I saw "» Ubuntu » Packages » cosmic (18.10) » utils » sed" in the page you mentioned. So it should be a Ubuntu 18.10 package, not 19.04.

Comment: This version will overwrite existing one. This is how APT works. So for  `sed --version` you will get 4.5. Thanks, fixed typo.

Comment: I would add the usual caveat that if you do this you no longer get automatic bugfix/security upgrades.

Comment: @fkraiem thanks, added this in bold. But also need to mention that installation from source for example has the same caveat...